# No se puede modificar la información de las cabeceras

Tags: php7

tengo un bug me me ha estado acosando durante mucho tiempo y es que parece que en php cuando quiero usar el cambio de locación para refrescar la página por ejemplo:

```
header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
```

Me aparece la advertencia de que no se pueden modificar la información de las cabeceras una vez hayan sido enviadas lo que sucede es que me lanza el mensaje en vez de llevarme a la página que quiero, ocurre en los siguiente metodos:

```
public function add()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $product_id = $_GET['id'];
        } else {
            header('Location:' . base_url);
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $indice => $elemento) {
                if ($elemento['id_product'] == $product_id) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$indice]['units']++;
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (!isset($counter) || $counter == 0) {
            // Conseguir producto
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setId($product_id);
            $product = $product->getOne();
            
            // Añadir al carrito
            if (is_object($product)) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
                    "id_product" => $product->id,
                    "price" => $product->price,
                    "units" => 1,
                    "product" => $product
                );
            }
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['index'])) {
            $index = $_GET['index'];
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
    }

    public function up()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['index'])) {
            $index = $_GET['index'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['units']++;
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
    }

    public function down()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['index'])) {
            $index = $_GET['index'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['units']--;

            if ($_SESSION['cart'][$index]['units'] == 0) {
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);
            }
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
    }

    public function delete_all()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);
        header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
    }
```

Los metodos simplemente son para añadir o quitar productos al carrito de la compra y cada metodo termina en:

```
header("Location:" . base_url . "cart/index");
```

Para refrescar la página pero me sale el error, ¿cómo hago para refrescar los cambios sin el problema de modificar las cabeceras?, si quito en la configuración de el servidor los mensajes de error simplemente me aparece una pantalla en blanco pero la idea es que me muestre exactamente la misma página pero con los cambios hechos con las preferencias del usuario.

Comment: Ese problema suele ocurrir porque antes de enviar las cabeceras no debe salir nada por pantalla y debe estar saliendo algo, sea un mensaje de error, sea una advertencia, sea código que muestras con `echo`, `print` u otro. Revisa el log de errores o pon temporalmente estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script, así podrás ver qué es lo que está saliendo antes de enviar las cabeceras y corregir el problema: `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Lo he hecho y me ha salido el error de que no puedo modificar las cabeceras después de haber sido enviadas. el problema yo creo es que tengo que simular un refresco con JavaScript porque con php no se puede.

Comment: ¿Podrías pulsar en [edit] y agregar el mensaje de error completo? En el mensaje suele decir en qué parte fueron enviadas las cabeceras: *en la línea tal del archivo tal*. Así podrás indentificar dónde está ocurriendo salida antes de las cabeceras.

Comment: Otra cosa, si estás usando Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, es un error redirigir desde el servidor. Lo que debes hacer es responder al cliente y redirigir desde el cliente si fuera necesario. Dado que no veo tu contexto Javascript no te puedo decir más, pero algunos cometen ese error, dejando plantado al cliente que espera una respuesta, no una redirección desde el servidor. Eso no quita que en cualquier caso, tengas el control de todo lo que sale en el servidor, para ofrecer al cliente una respuesta adecuada, por ejemplo, cuando espera un JSON válido.

Comment: Esta es una aplicación hecha casi enteramente con PHP nativo, solo tiene JavaScript para cuando PHP se me queda corto por ejemplo: menús desplegables etc, lo que quiero decir es que independientemente de que me salga el error de que no se pueden modificar las cabeceras, igualmente mi código PHP hace todo lo que me debe de hacer sin problemas solo que no se reflejan los cambios en ese momento  si no que me sale el error, si retrocedo y voy a la misma vista los cambios ya se ven, por eso digo que se puede simular un refresh con JavaScript.

Comment: Se puede simular un refresh con Javascript o con PHP. Conviene centrarse en el problema, si es que quieres usar cabeceras en PHP. Y el problema es que algo está saliendo antes de las cabeceras. Eso significa que algo anda mal en tu código (un error, un warning) y/o que no tienes control total de él. Si quieres controlar tu código, entonces tienes que ver dónde y por qué está saliendo algo que no tienes controlado para corregirlo. Si cambias de opinión y quieres resolverlo desde Javascript, adelante. En ese caso esta pregunta pierde su sentido. De todos modos, la idea de simular un refresh ...

Comment: ... hace pensar a un problema de diseño, o al uso de código antiguo. Hoy día esos *trucos* del siglo pasado no son necesarios, a no ser que haya una razón poderosa que lo justifique. En resumen, si quieres seguir con esta pregunta, resolviendo el problema de los `header` en PHP, conviene que muestres el mensaje de error completo, el cual te dice en qué archivo y en qué línea se te está escapando algo en el buffer de salida. Si decides resolver desde Javascript y tienes algún problema, entonces deberás abrir una nueva pregunta donde muestres el código Javascript que no funciona.

Comment: Hoy día esos trucos del siglo pasado no son necesarios, pero estoy practicando hacer una aplicación con PHP nativo, por si me tengo que topar con un proyecto viejo en un futuro trabajo, y los frameworks de PHP todos tienen algo de JavaScript adentro, es una lastima que no consiga ayuda de parte de otros desarrolladores en esta página y chatgpt si me resuelva los problemas. hacer un refresh con javaScript fue la solución, y el error de las cabeceras no tiene mas, me he topado con ese error miles de veces y siempre es lo mismo me advierte de que no me puede mostrar algo porque la información

Comment: ya se envio....